# Wrong result using arraycopy

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to copy two Byte arrays into another. The problem is that the first element of the result Byte is strange, I get **0xFFFFFF80** instead of **0x80**.
the code I'm using is:

```
    this.IC_SUBMIT_APDU = new byte[13];
    byte[] prefix = {
        (byte) 0x80,
        (byte) 0x20,
        (byte) 0x07,
        (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0x08
    };
    System.arraycopy(prefix , 0, this.IC_SUBMIT_APDU, 0, prefix.length);

    for(int i=0; i<this.IC_SUBMIT_APDU.length ; i++)
        System.out.println("" + Integer.toHexString(this.IC_SUBMIT_APDU[i]));
```

when I give it this argument:

```
{
    (byte) 0x41,
    (byte) 0x43,
    (byte) 0x4F,
    (byte) 0x53,
    (byte) 0x54,
    (byte) 0x45,
    (byte) 0x53,
    (byte) 0x54
}
```

it produces the following result:

```
ffffff80
20
7
0
8
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

WHy do I get that  **0xFFFFFF80** ? am I not supposed to get **0x80** ??

Comment: You must read it from right to left two numbers at a time, so you have `80 FF FF FF`. As said mattm in his answer, the `FFFFFF` part comes from somewhere else or is filler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with `System.arrayCopy`.

In fact, `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((byte) 0x80));` will also print `ffffff80`.

You have an arithmetic overflow when casting hex `0x80` as byte, since its decimal value is `128`, i.e. `1` more than `byte`'s capacity (`Byte.MAX_VALUE`, or `127`) and overflows to `-128`.

Note that in turn, `Integer.toHexString` returns the representation of an *unsigned* integer, hence the additional overflow.

Answer (score 3):

0xFFFFFF80 is more than one byte. The 0xFFFFFF portion is probably from  a different print statement that you have not shown.

Comment: I have no print statement before this one.

Answer (score 0):

your are copying correctly the only 5 elements present in ***ic_submit_apdu_prefix*** ...

hint: 0x80 with 8 bits is -128 (2 complement)

> 0xffffff80 = -128
>
> 0x20 = 32
>
> 7
>
> 0
>
> 8
>
> 0

the rest is zero. (default initial primitive value)